# How do I edit specific part from lineedit in Python?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a python app that change mac address. I use lineEdit. I want to lock ( not edit) Colon `:`

mac address is like that: > XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX

I want to change only `XX` not `:` . I want to fill only 12 characters .

How can I do that?

Comment: [`QLineEdit.setInputMask()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop).

Comment: Where Can I put this. My command is `self.specificWindow.lineEdit.text()`

Comment: Read the documentation linked above and learn how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal example on how to use [`setInputMask`](https://pythonpyqt.com/pyqt-qlineedit/), as mentioned in the comments:

[image]

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLineEdit

app = QApplication([])

edit = QLineEdit()
# input mask for a MAC adress
# mask characters have been replaced with the blank character (a space '_')
input_mask = "HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH;_"
edit.setInputMask(input_mask)
edit.show()

app.exec()
```